# What is the efficient way to check if a string is present in a list of strings in the ngIf angular directive

Tags: javascript, angular

This is what I am doing currently but wanted to know if there is a better way of doing it instead of using multiple || expressions.

```
 <button
            *ngIf="(element.account.status && (element.account.status === 'DRAFT') || (element.account.status === 'PENDING') || (element.account.status === 'REVERT') || (element.account.status === 'REVIEW')); else addDisabled"
            id="add-account" mat-icon-button (click)="openDialog(element.accountType)">
            <img src="../../../../assets/add.svg" />
 </button>
 <ng-template #addDisabled>
            <button id="add-account" mat-icon-button [disabled]="true">
              <img class="intro" src="../../../../svgs/add-disabled.svg" />
            </button>
 </ng-template>
```

Comment: You can use `['DRAFT', 'PENDING', 'REVERT', 'REVIEW'].includes(element.account.status)`

Answer (score 1):

Use a property like this:

```
 <button
            *ngIf="allowAdd; else addDisabled"
            id="add-account" mat-icon-button (click)="openDialog(element.accountType)">
            <img src="../../../../assets/add.svg" />
 </button>
```

then in your javascript (e.g in your controller), set the property like this:

```
$scope.allowAdd = ['DRAFT', 'PENDING', 'REVERT', 'REVIEW'].includes(element.account.status);
```

> Just make sure you update the boolean property if your `account.status`
> changes.

---

If it's too complex to keep track of when `account.status` changes in your controller so you can update the boolean property, you could also add the `includes()` call directly in the `*ngIf` as Chris suggested in a comment, but there are two issues:

1. As your logic changes again (or your list of status grows), it may become **unreadable** again in the future
2. Angular would need to execute the `includes()` call on every change detection cycle (even if the account status didn't change), in order to check if the condition changed (it **may lead to performance issues**).

The View should not keep complex logic checks, this should be in your controller, the view should rely on a simple property instead, this provides a better separation of concerns, improves code readability/maintainability and avoids performance issues.